# Estimated lambda exponential distribution

Tags: simulation, distribution, exponential, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to calculate lambda that is the rate of exponential distribution. For example if I have an interval of 5 seconds and I have 4 objects (on average) how is lambda calculated? I need formulas to calculate it.  Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post what you've already done and do show what effort you've already put in. If there is some error or efficiency issue in your code, somebody may look into it. But no one's going to give ready made code here.

Comment: You may want to try here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The rate is the number of occurrences per time unit (total number of occurrences / total time). For your case, 4 per 5 time units or a rate of 0.8 per time unit. The mean time between occurrences will be the inverse of this, or 1.25 time units.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about [Exponential_distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)

> the exponential distribution is the probability distribution that
>   describes the time between events in [...] a process in which events
>   occur continuously and independently at a constant average rate